# Microsoft.Expression.Drawing for VS 2019

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio-2019, blend

I'm in the process of migrating a .net 4.5 wpf application to .net 4.8 using Visual Studio 2019, I managed to do so successfully. But recently I opened the solution on a brand new development machine which only have VS 2019 and noticed that the solution failing to build because it can't find two DLLs;

```
Microsoft.Expression.Drawing     
System.Windows.Interactivity
```

For `System.Windows.Interactivity`, I'm planning to use `Microsoft.Xaml.Behaviors.Wpf` as advised by the SO community but I can't find anything on `Microsoft.Expression.Drawing`. Any help regarding would be helpful.

I had VS 2012 on my old machine which had Blend SDK which is why I didn't got these errors in the first migration.

PS: I found this [nuget](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Unnoficial.Microsoft.Expression.Drawing/) package, but looking for a legitimate solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The "legitimate" solution is still to download the [Blend SDK](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=10801) from microsoft.com.

It isn't tied to any specific Visual Studio version.

If you are using `Microsoft.Expression.Drawing`, you have a dependency on the Blend SDK regardless of which version of Visual Studio you are using to develop and compile your application.

There is no such thing as a "Microsoft.Expression.Drawing for VS 2019".

Comment: Is there a package I can replace instead of Microsoft.Expression.Drawing @mm8?

Comment: No, at least no official one.

Comment: Mar/2022 - this link seems to be dead now.

Answer (score 1):

This Nuget package - [Expression.Blend.Sdk.WPF](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Expression.Blend.Sdk.WPF/1.0.1?_src=template) can provide references of the both mentioned DLLs,

```
Microsoft.Expression.Drawing
System.Windows.Interactivity
```